# git commit searches source and extracts comments

Tags: git

I'm just wondering, say in my sources I were to write some kind of comment like

```
# .GIT: Fixed da big bug man!
```

So these might appear here and there in various source files with detailed explanations (as in the example!).

Then on git commit it would first scan all the sources, extract those comments for the commit message and commit it. Extra would be to remove those comments form the source files (ya a little dangerous but hey, live on the edge).

Does this make sense? Is there something already out there for say the hooks? I would have thought it a popular request but unless I'm searching the wrong keywords, I've found nothing. Or is this a really, really bad idea or impossible?

And yes, as you guessed it I'm new to git.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's possible (witrh some tricks, yes)
2. It can be done with hooks (precommit at least)
3. Yes, it **have not sense** and it's **bad idea** and result of dirty chaotic workflow and poor planning

All and any commit (and developer behind scene) **must** follow paradigm "Commit often! Commit fast!" and if you use "commit per atomic job" or lesser (one job *may* be affected in *some amount* of commits) idea, you can not write and combine in commit message done-list

Comment: Besides that, there is `git add -p` which allows you to choose which changes you want to commit. So even after making multiple changes you can easily commit them separately as long as they didn't change the same lines.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - but separation of files doesn't refresh memory, if a lot of unrelated tasks was done in different files in a long time